# my code to convert from byte array to long doesn't work

Tags: java

I have written code in java, to convert from byte array to long, code is here:

```
public static long bTol(byte[] b_arr) {
        long res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b_arr.length; i++) {
            res += ((b_arr[i] & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) << ((b_arr.length - 1 - i) * 8));
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I get different number when I run this code, but i can't understand what is problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mask a single byte, otherwise the sign extension pollutes your result:

```
public static long bTol(byte[] b_arr) {
    long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b_arr.length; i++) {
        res += (long)(b_arr[i] & 0xFF) << ((b_arr.length - 1 - i) * 8);
    }
    return res;
}
```

You may also use available methods (assuming that the byte array has length 8, as it should):

```
public static long bToL(byte[] b_arr) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate( b_arr.length );
    buf.put( b_arr );
    return buf.getLong(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
res += ((b_arr[i] & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) << ((b_arr.length - 1 - i) * 8));
```

By this :

```
res += ((long) b_arr[i] & 0xFFL) << (8 * i);
```